# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but request goes through

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, cors

I'm currently deploying a basic API to my live server and I'm running into (what I think is) a CORS problem but there is some behavior going on that I can't explain.

I'm communicating from an AngularJS front-end to a Laravel 5 (+ [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)) back-end.

I started testing with a simple jQuery AJAX call (below) and when I make a request from my local Vagrant environment (`http://dev.example.local/test.html`) to `http://api.example.com/v1/matches` I get an error about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The weird thing is that the request does come through because the information is stored in the database via the Laravel-based API correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.example.com/v1/players',
    data: {
        "username": "username",
        "first_name": "First",
        "last_name": "Last",
        "nickname": ""
    }
}).always(function(r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```

Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/v1/players. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://other.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The `console.log(r)` returns `{readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}`

I developed the application locally using a Homestead VM (API) and a Vagrant environment (application) and it's working correctly within these environments...

Some observations:

- Each of these requests shows up with Method: `POST`, Status: `200 OK`, Type: `xhr` in my Chrome Developer Tools.
- Tools like Postman and PhpStorm's RESTful service tester correctly execute the request and the data is added without errors.

Any ideas on how to further debug this problem are welcome... I've been trying to wrap my head around this for the entire day now and I just don't know what's causing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your server must return an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. For example, if the request is being sent from http://stackoverflow.com, then your server must return this header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://stackoverflow.com`. You can determine, server-side, what the origin is by looking at the `Origin` header on the request. If your server does *not* return this header in the response, you will not have any access to the properties of the response browser-side (such as the status code, headers, or message body). The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is at the center of this restriction.

The reason you are not seeing any similar issues when the request is sent by Postman or PhpStorm's RESTful service tester is due to the fact that these services do *not* send an `Origin` header with the request, as they are not subject to the Same Origin policy. By default, the browser will append this header to any cross-origin ajax requests, as browsers *are* subject to the Same Origin Policy. In my previous scenario, the request header would look like this: `Origin: http://stackoverflow.com`. Browsers that implement [the CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) are required to add this request header so the server is able to determine if the origin of the request has been whitelisted for cross-origin ajax requests. If this is the case, the server will return the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If not, it can simply omit the header. Browsers that do not implement the CORS spec will simply refuse to send such an ajax request.

Regarding your bewilderment as to why the request is being sent in the first place, that comes down to a distinction between "simple" and "non-simple" CORS requests. For simple CORS requests, the request will *always* be sent to the server, but the client/JS will not be able to parse the response without proper acknowledgement from the server. Some CORS requests are *not* simple, so to speak. These are, for example, `DELETE` or `PATCH` requests, or `POST`/`GET` requests that contain non-standard headers (such as X-headers or a `Content-Type` of "application/json" as opposed to "multipart/form-data"). In other words, a request is *not* simple if it cannot be sent without JavaScript. For example, a `<form>` submit, or a GET request from a `<script src="...">` will always send "simple" requests. For non-simple requests, the browser must "preflight" the request. This means that the browser sends an intermediate request, called a preflight, *before* the original request. This preflight request is an `OPTIONS` request. The server must than return headers in the response to this preflight that acknowledge any non-standard properties of the original request. If it does, then the browser will send the original request.

You can read more about preflighting and CORS in general on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: I knew most of what you said already but the explanation for why the request would come through was new to me, thanks!

I'm 99% sure the back-end has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*` as it is a public API, is there any way to test this?

And since I'm running AJAX POST requests via jQuery they are non-simple, right? So they should send the preflight request. Should I be able to see this in de Network tab of Chrome devtools, as I'm not seeing any.

Comment: Turns out I implemented the laravel-cors package incorrectly or something. I added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to my apache2 vhost and it's working correctly now...

Comment: If the browser is not sending a preflight, then the requests are "simple". Makes no difference if you are sending them with jQuery or not. Requests are only non-simple if they contain some of the things I mentioned in my answer. For example, if you set the content type of the request sent by jQuery to application/json, the browser would preflight the request. The MDN article I linked to goes into more detail.

Comment: It wasn't obvious in your question that you understood what CORS was or that you were already attempting to return a proper CORS header. I now see that you mentioned laraval-cors though.

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks for the detailed explanation, it certainly refreshed my memory on CORS. And I ended up testing it a little more thanks to your answer so I'll mark it as accepted.