# Many to many relationship in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In one of my current projects, I have a scenario where a company can have many tags and a tag can be belonged to many companies. To achieve this, In my model I have defined as follows

```
// Company model
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Company extends Model {
        public function tags(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
        } }
```

and

```
// Tag model

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function companies(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_tag', 'company_id', 'tag_id')->withTimestamps();   
    }
}
```

In my CompanyController Store function, after the company and tags are saved I have added the following line

```
$company->tags()->attach(1);
```

I have an AngularJS front end separate project and the backend as a separate project. When I added the above line in the controller, it gives me an access origin error. When I removed that, data get saved properly.

Comment: Did you selected the company from DB prior to attaching

Comment: Yes, this is the correct code:

`$newcompany = Company::find(1);

$company->tags()->attach($newcompany);`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an angular issue. Is your server returning the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoursite.com
```

Found in the accepted answer on this related (duplicate?) question:
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but request goes through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338596/access-control-allow-origin-error-but-request-goes-through)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it gave me a great idea about the CORS, but the real problem that I had was in my api app name, I renamed it to something else, but I was still calling through App. now its fixed

Comment: @Mujahid glad you figured it out!